# Varchar PrimaryKey. Clustered or nonclustered?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key, clustered-index

I am working on a legacy database. The primary key is clustered *varchar(128)* and the table contains a high volume of data.

Does it necessarily help performance if I change the clustered PK to nonclustered?

Changing the table to a heap would at least it prevent more data fragmentation after inserting any new rows (to the best of my knowledge - I am not a DBA). I also have similar problem with *uniqueidentifier* primary keys here.

Comment: uniqueidentifiers are _awful_ clustering keys. I'd recommend having a clustered index rather than leaving it as a heap, are there any integer columns your could use instead?

Having no clustered index will still result in fragmentation, as the only way a base table can be defragged is for its clustered index to be rebuilt (or created).

Comment: In order to answer this question, we're going to need more information about the table and it's other indexes. And how many rows. There are good reasons for having a clustered index, but you need to choose it carefully. A good clustered index is generally narrow, unique, and ever increasing. So if you stop clustering on this column, think about what column(s) you will cluster on. A good clustered index will help your nonclustered indexes perform.

Comment: @ThomasPullen it's not only one table. There are many tables in this db which have similar issue. I am gonna investigate a bit and find good candidates for being clustered index in each table.